# Going from Table View to Different Detail Views in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, detailsview

I'm a beginning programmer.  And I had a question.
I currently have a Table View in my app.  There are three rows to it, History, Theory, and Applied Use.  I would like each one to go to a different detail view.  However, each one only clicks to one of the detail views.

I think the issue is at

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Magnets_AU_Aubrey" bundle:[
```

Please help any.  The three XIB's are Magnets_AU_Aubrey, Magnets_History_Aubrey, and Magnets_Theory_Aubrey

```
#import "DisclosureButtonController.h"
#import "NavAppDelegate.h"
#import "DisclosureDetailController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DisclosureButtonController
@synthesize list;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"History", @"Theory", @"Applied Use", nil];
    self.list = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.list = nil;
    [childController release], childController = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [list release];
    [childController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [list count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString * DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier =
    @"DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *rowString = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = rowString;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    [rowString release];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Magnets_AU_Aubrey" bundle:[
                                                                                                          NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
     dvController = nil;
     }



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (childController == nil) {
        childController = [[DisclosureDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MagnetsAubreyCreditsDisclosureDetail" bundle:nil];
    }
    childController.title = @"Disclosure Button Pressed";
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *selectedMovie = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *detailMessage = [[NSString alloc]
                               initWithFormat:@"School",selectedMovie];
    childController.message = detailMessage;
    childController.title = selectedMovie;
    [detailMessage release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"History", @"Theory", @"Applied Use", nil];
```

Now do the same for xibs. Create array and fill it with xib names. Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get correct xib name apply the same logic as you do in cellForRowAtIndexPath for getting cell text.

Comment: I'm going to try to take this one step at a time because I'm pretty new at this:  Would the array look like this:  xibArray *array = [[xibArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Magnets_History_Aubrey", @"Magnets_Theory_Aubrey", @"Magnets_AU_Aubrey", nil];  in the line right below NSArray?

Comment: You should read this document as first step: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf

Comment: I'm really confused.  I understand the basic code, but I still feel lost.  Please help.  This is for a school project and would really appreciate the help.